# I have nextjs application that uploads files but my response.data returns empty

Tags: reactjs, next.js, upload

This is the application code in Nextjs.
my context

````
import fileSize from "filesize";
import { api } from "../services/api";
import { randomBytes } from "crypto";

type UploadedFilesType = {
    file: File;
    id: string;
    name: string;
    filesize: string;
    preview: string;
    progress: number;
    uploaded: boolean;
    error: boolean;
    url: any;
}

type UploadedContextType = {
    uploadedFiles: UploadedFilesType[],
    handleUpload: (files: File[]) => void
}

type UploadType = {
    children: ReactNode;
}


export const UploadContext = createContext({} as UploadedContextType);

export function UploadContexProvider({ children }: UploadType) {

    const [uploadedFiles, setUploadedFiles] = useState<UploadedFilesType[]>([])

    function handleUpload(files: File[]) {
        const filesUploaded = files.map(file => ({
            file,
            id: randomBytes(16).toString('hex'),
            name: file.name,
            filesize: fileSize(file.size),
            preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
            progress: 0,
            uploaded: false,
            error: false,
            url: null
        }));

        setUploadedFiles(uploadedFiles.concat(filesUploaded));

        filesUploaded.forEach(processUpload);
    }

    const updateFile = useCallback((id: string, data: UploadedFilesType) => {
        setUploadedFiles((state) => state.map((file) => (file.id === id ? { ...file, ...data } : file)))
    }, [])


    async function processUpload(uploadedFile: UploadedFilesType) {
        const datafile = new FormData();

        datafile.append("file", uploadedFile.file, uploadedFile.name);


        api.post("uploads", datafile, {
            onUploadProgress: e => {
                const progress = Number(Math.round(e.loaded * 100 / e.total));
                updateFile(uploadedFile.id, {
                    progress,
                    file: uploadedFile.file,
                    id: uploadedFile.id,
                    name: uploadedFile.name,
                    filesize: uploadedFile.filesize,
                    preview: uploadedFile.preview,
                    uploaded: uploadedFile.uploaded,
                    error: uploadedFile.error,
                    url: uploadedFile.url
                })
            }
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })

    }

    return (
        <UploadContext.Provider value={{ uploadedFiles, handleUpload }}>
            {children}
        </UploadContext.Provider>
    )
}```

My upload component:

``` import { useContext } from "react";
import Dropzone from "react-dropzone";
import { UploadContext } from "../../contexts/UploadContext";

import styles from "./styles.module.scss";


export function Upload() {

    const { handleUpload } = useContext(UploadContext);

    function renderDragContainer(isDragActive, isDragReject) {
        if (!isDragActive) {
            return styles.dropContainer
        }

        if (isDragReject) {
            return styles.isDragReject
        }

        return styles.isDragActive
    }

    return (

        <Dropzone accept="image/*" onDropAccepted={handleUpload} >
            {({ getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive, isDragReject }) => {
                return (
                    <div {...getRootProps()} className={renderDragContainer(isDragActive, isDragReject)}>
                        <input {...getInputProps()} />

                    </div>
                )
            }}
        </Dropzone>
    )
} ```

my only page in the app:

``` import { useContext } from "react";
import { FileList } from "../components/FileList";
import { Upload } from "../components/Upload";
import { UploadContext } from "../contexts/UploadContext";
import styles from "../styles/home.module.scss";


export default function Home() {

  const { uploadedFiles } = useContext(UploadContext);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.content}>
        <Upload />
        {!!uploadedFiles.length && (
          <FileList files={uploadedFiles} />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
````

What happens is that I send the file to dropzone it saves the file but my response.data returns empty I don't know why. Being that I need the return of this response.data to update the upload status, it is worth mentioning that I am using typescript but I have already built this same application using reactjs and it worked perfectly in jsx format

````
config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
data: ""
headers: {content-length: '0', content-type: 'application/json'}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 201
statusText: "Created"
[[Prototype]]: Object  ```
````

Comment: What were you expecting the get back in `response.data`? Can you share the code for the `services/api` as well as the `uploads` endpoint?

Comment: ```   import axios from "axios";

export const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8080"
})  ```